# How can I put the Image in the top-left corner, while still being responsive?

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

I am new to Angular/Bootstrap and currently trying to put an image on top of the navigation bar in the top left corner. Using padding/margin could fix the problem with a normal resolution/static screen size, changing the size put the image elsewhere.

I have tried to use padding and margin, but as I said, it was not possible, to make it "sticky" in the top left corner, when changing the browser sice.
Also using the bootstrap classes, for example "pull-right" (just for test-cases) did not work.

My current code looks like:

```
<header>
    <div class="cloud">
        <!-- Navigation -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark $green static-top">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                    <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-logo.svg?v=a010291124bf" class="pull-right" alt="" width="431.27" height="55.35">
                </a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive"
                    aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home
                                <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Profile</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Impressum</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="first">
        <h1>TestSite</h1>
    </div>
</header>
```

I expected an image in the top left corner that is responsively staying there while changing browsersizes/devices

Comment: not too sure of expected result, but instead pull-right, make your own custom class using  vh, vw , vmin or vmax values to set your average padding/margin.  https://web-design-weekly.com/2014/11/18/viewport-units-vw-vh-vmin-vmax/ - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this code to see, whether this is the desired result. Fully working demo is available [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jnelsonin/5x8duh2s/7/)

Main Changes made on your code is.

1. added CSS class `bg-dark` and removed `$green static-top` on nav. `<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">`
2. fixed the width of brand image to 50%, using css. This can be changed to some other value.
3. removed `width` and `height` attributes from `img` tag.

```css
.navbar-brand img{
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- 
  Bootstrap docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs
-->

<div class="container">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                    <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-logo.svg?v=a010291124bf">
                </a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive"
                    aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home
                                <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Profile</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Impressum</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

  
</div>
```